# What did she name her son?

Tags: riddle

Cindy Tyler gave birth to a beautiful boy. She wanted her husband's suggestion to name him. Her husband was away on a mining exploration job. She texted to him

> For our beautiful boy please send me a name suggestion

Her husband, a mining and materials scientist and a riddle enthusiast sent her the following note

> Burning and radiating, is light and strong, noble, Hope universally
>   abundant the boy

What did he suggest?

HINT

All about rearranging words to make a sentence. Then look for the Elements decribed and rearrange them!

Hint 2
Noble Metal one element

And I gave a specific name Cindy Tyler!

Hint 3
Rearranging

The boy is Noble, radiating, burning, light and strong and universally abundant.

Comment: hmmmm the word-property tag is bothering me...

Comment: Because there is no sentence property Tag!

Comment: On a scale from zero to Anirudhnew, how badly will I go wrong if I assume that Cindy's husband would only suggest common English (US) names?

Comment: Very common name

Comment: Shall I assume that the capital H in the second block is intentional?

Comment: Can I just clarify whether the punctuation is important? As in, are the commas used to separate parts of the name in a meaningful way? I think I have an answer, but the commas mess it up.

Comment: HINT  Rearrange the words in the sentence

Comment: You can rearrange this sentence in any one of like 40 different ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name is

> Agustin.

Noble

> Ag (silver) is a noble metal.

Radiating

> U (uranium) is radioactive.

Burning

> S (sulfur) is also known as brimstone, meaning "burning stone."

Light and strong

> Ti (titanium) is a light and strong metal.

Universally abundant

> N (nitrogen) is one of the most [abundant elements in the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements).

Comment: FINALLY!    Austin could work too I realized. +1

Answer (score 11):

Somewhat far-fetched, but (I believe) still valid answer:

> Santiago (yes, very common name in United States)

Explanation

> **Sun** is *burning* (thermonuclear reactions) and *radiating* (sunlight).
>  **Titanium** (chemical symbol **Ti**) is relatively *light* but *strong* metal.
>  **Silver** (symbol **Ag**) is *noble* metal.
>  **Oxygen** (symbol **O**) is *universally abundant* element.
>  Putting together, we get *SunTiAgO* or Santiago.

Comment: Very logical good try. +1 for that. In my answer all those things are elements. Sun is not .

Answer (score 10):

his name is:

> Krypton

explanation:

> **Burning and radiating, is light and strong, noble**-Krypton is a chemical element . It is a member of group 18 **noble** gases,is used in **light**ing and Filled incandescent bulbs,photography...**Hope universally abundant the boy**-And according to the original plot of Superman he was born on the fictional planet Krypton.Superman He is a fictional super hero character And he is very **strong**

Comment: I like this, but "Very common name" - @DEEM

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

> Ralph

Burning and radiating

> Radium - radiating radiation

light and strong

> Aluminium - it is lightweight and durable

noble

> not sure about this one...

Hope universally abundant the boy

> Hydrogen - it is universally abundant and begins with H

All of that adds up to

> (Ra + Al + P + H)

That's all I got for now...

Comment: Please tell me how far off track I am

Answer (score 5):

The answer may be...

> Cole... a play on "coal"

Burning and radiating...

> Coal as a fuel source for heaters and fireplaces

light and strong

> Varieties of coal can be light or strong

noble

> Noble Group is a commodities company, and thermal coal is one of their key commodities (grasping here...)

Hope

> A reference to the Hope Diamond...?

universally abundant

> There's lots of it around... for a while

Answer (score 4):

not much of a name, but it is common and abundant:

> Corn

Reasoning:

> Carbon(C) is light and strong and burns and variations radiate, By definition nothing burns without Oxygen (O), and is also abundant (Carbon based life), and Radon (RN) is a noble gas and yet somehow is a harmful by-product of the natural decay of uranium that is presently emitting/radiating from the soil in the Midwest and other places.  The result, Corn is also hopefully universally abundant because it provides for many things (fuel, food, income, etc.) and corn is a very common word.

The sentence:

> Hope universally the boy is light, strong, abundant and radiating, burning, and noble.

Alternatively:

> Harvy: **H**ydrogen, **Ar**, **V**anadium, **Y**ttrium Hydrogen is abundant, light, and burns; Argon is a noble gas and can radiate in lights similar to Neon; Vanadium and Yttrium transition metals like Titanium so presumably strong. The name also used to be fairly common.

Answer (score 2):

Name:

> Harper

Rearrange:

> *universally abundant*, *Noble*, *burning strong bright light*, the boy *radiating*  hope

Gives us:

> Hydrogen(H), Argon(Ar), Phosphorous(P), Erbium(Er)(which has 9 radioactive isotopes)

only issue:

> Pretty sure that is a girls name...

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be

> Helium

Reasoning:

> The boy is light and strong
> Helium is lighter than air.
>
> Noble.
> Helium is a noble gas.
>
> Universally abundant.
> Helium is abundant in the universe.
>
> Burning and radiating hope.
> Helium burns in stars.